# Showing summation of disjoint sets can be split

Tags: summation

> Take three sets $X,Y,Z \subseteq V$  $$\sum_{u\in X\cup Y}\sum_{v\in
>  Z}f(u,v)=\sum_{u\in X}\sum_{v\in Z}f(u,v) + \sum_{u\in Y}\sum_{v\in Z}f(u,v) \text{ if
>  $X \cap Y=\varnothing$}$$

It seems obvious to me that is true since each pair only occurs once. Is there any way to show this formally via a direct proof?

Comment: I'd say the answer depends on context. First, are we talking finite or infinite sets? And it all depends on what related results you can rely on. One way would rely on showing that the sum on the left is a (single) sum over $(u,v)\in(X\cup Y)\times Z$, and similarly for the sums on the right – and noting that $(X\cup Y)\times Z$ is the disjoint union of $X\times Z$ and $Y\times Z$.

Comment: They are all finite, also what do you mean by "related results you can rely on" ?

Comment: By that, I mean results like: The sums over disjoint sets add up to the sum over the union, and the double sums over two sets is a single sum over the cross product (as I mentioned in my first comment above). If you assume nothing known, other than the commutativity and associativity of addition, proving an inequality like this is going to be a lot more work.

Comment: The inner sum doesn't really matter, as it's the same for a given $u$ in all three terms; you can just think of it as a function of $u$. So can you show that if $X\cap Y=\emptyset$ then $\sum_{u\in X\cup Y} g(u) = \sum_{u\in X} g(u) + \sum_{u\in Y} g(u)$ ?